# Добавление в список при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: android, recyclerview, list, arraylist

Проблема заключается в следующем : Есть список с продуктами ReyclerView и есть рядом с каждым продуктом кнопка при нажатии на которую продукт добавляется в список,который в дальнейшем будет выводиться в новой `activity`, как "список выбранных продуктов".  Я пытаюсь это реализовать, прописал метод,запускаю и мне вылетает ошибка:

```
03-11 13:39:40.921 9503-9503/com.example.coursework E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.coursework, PID: 9503
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.coursework/com.example.coursework.ProductSelectionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2702)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.coursework.ProductSelectionActivity.onCreate(ProductSelectionActivity.java:52)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Вот сам код:

```
public class ProductSelectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DatabaseReference reference;
private ArrayList<ProductModel>list;
private ProductAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<String>basketList;
private TextView productName;
private Button addProductToBasket;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_selection);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.product_list);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    productName =  findViewById(R.id.product_name);

    addProductToBasket = findViewById(R.id.addProductToBasket);
    addProductToBasket.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            basketList = new ArrayList<String>();
            basketList.add(productName.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(ProductSelectionActivity.this, basketList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String prodPosition = intent.getStringExtra("position");

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products").child(prodPosition);
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list = new ArrayList<ProductModel>();
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                ProductModel p = new ProductModel();
                p.setProductName(dataSnapshot1.child("name").getValue().toString());

                list.add(p);


            }
            adapter = new ProductAdapter(ProductSelectionActivity.this,list);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

}

Кнопка называется `addProductToBasket`. `ProductName` это `TextView`в списке, где выводится название продукта.

Код Адаптера :

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder>{

private Context context;
private ArrayList<ProductModel> list;

public ProductAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ProductModel> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    return new ProductViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.product_item_cardview,parent,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position) { // подставляются значения в RecyclerView

    holder.textProduct.setText(list.get(position).getProductName());
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textProduct;
    CardView cv;


    public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_product);
        textProduct = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);



    }
}
```

}

Comment: в ошибке написано что кнопку не могут найти, может кнопка не инициализирована?

Comment: судя по коду у вас кастомный список, сделанный через адаптер, для того чтобы все работало, вам нужно инициализировать кнопку не в активности где список, а в адаптере, покажите код адаптера, если он есть :)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko Добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам в вашем адаптере нужно чтобы было так:

```
class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textProduct;
    CardView cv;
    Button btn;


    public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_product);
        textProduct = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        btn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addProductToBasket);


    }
}
```

и дальше в onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position) { // подставляются значения в RecyclerView

    holder.textProduct.setText(list.get(position).getProductName());

holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
}
```

### UPD

Делаете интерфейс:

```
 public interface RecyclerViewClickListener {
    public void recyclerViewListClicked(View v, int position);
}
```

дальше в активности пишете:

```
@Override
public void recyclerViewListClicked(View v, int position){... ...}
myAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(context, this);
```

и в адаптере:

```
private static RecyclerViewClickListener itemListener;

 class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textProduct;
    CardView cv;
    Button btn;


    public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_product);
        textProduct = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        btn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addProductToBasket);

        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
@Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           itemListener.recyclerViewListClicked(v, this.getPosition());     

       }
}
```

но мне если честно как-то легче предствляется через синглтон все сделать, будет проще и быстрее :) надеюсь у вас все получится :)

Comment: и чтобы получить название продукта, я прописать должен так ?  `public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, final int position) { // подставляются значения в RecyclerView

        holder.textProduct.setText(list.get(position).getProductName());

        holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                basketList = new ArrayList<String>();
                basketList.add(list.get(position).getProductName());
            }
        });
    }`

Comment: я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, я название продукта передавал в другой список basketList

Comment: я же потом смогу этот список передать через `putExtra` в другое `activity` ?

Comment: а вот это уже другой вопрос)) я бы вам советовал два варианта: либо сделать публичным глобальным массив в адаптере и доставать его уже там где вам нужно, либо сделать все через отдельный класс, потому что сейчас вы предлагаете при нажатии на кнопку сразу переходить в корзину

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko очень плохой способ в ViewHolder обрабатывать нажатия. Лучше реализовать интерфейс в адаптере и переопределить, чтобы получать результаты в активити (фрагменте)

Comment: @danilshik, да я про это читал статейку одну, но способ тем не менее был там освещен) интерфейс конечно лучший вариант для решения подобных задач

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko а можете подробно дать ваш ответ, как реализовать через интерфейс, пожалуйста ?

Comment: @danilshik или вы можете дать подробный ответ, как реализовать через интерфейс, пожалуйста ?

Comment: уже пишу, если что меня исправят :)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko тогда жду :)

Comment: у вас там довольно сложная система)) если у вас две активности в каждой свой список со своим адаптером, то для каждой активности и для каждого списка свой адаптер нужен :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90866/discussion-between-programmer-and-andrew-goroshko).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko сделано )